# My iPhone Simulator does't look like everyone else's

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

My iPhone 5 simulator looks different thank what other people have. It is framed like the legacy iPhone instead of the iPhone 5 skin/frame. I have found that the simulator does have the frame file but it is not showing up

Comment: That's cool. Do you have a question?

Comment: I wanted to know how to get that iPhone 5 looking simulator. Sorry if I worded it wrong

Comment: See the answer given. Also check to make sure that your version of XCode is up to date (4.6.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a non-retina 1920x1080 Mac display:

- The iPhone (legacy non-retina) simulator has a a full bezel complete with home button and "ear piece".
- The iPhone (Retina 3.5") screen has a home button and a slight bezel, but no "ear
  piece".
- The iPhone (Retina 4") simulator does not have a home button or a bezel.

You can change the device type in the simulator under the Hardware->Device menu.

In order to see the bezel, you must view the simulator at 100% scale. You can change the scale in the simulator under the Window->Scale menu.

Comment: I found that running the iPhone Retina 4" simulator on a retina MacBook pro will show the full bezel, complete with home button and ear piece, and on my 27" cinema display, it has a slight bezel with no ear piece. I think the simulator changes the appearance of the simulator, based on what screen it runs on, and how much room available you have.